# Combine several jpg of fixed cm size on one a4 pdf

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

How do I combine several jpg into one a4 pdf page such that each pdf has the same size, let's say a width of 9 cm?

I could probably do this with gimp but would prefer an automatic linux command line solution.

Comment: Imagemagick works in pixels, not cm. The default PDF density, I believe, is 72 dpi. So you need to convert 1 cm to pixels to figure out where to place it. You also will need to convert your 9 cm to pixels to know how to resize your images.

Comment: I don't find your question very clear. What OS are you using? Do you mean you want to get as many JPEGs on a page as possible, by making them all small? Or you just have 3 images and want to arrange them vertically or horizontally so they fit without resizing? I really can't tell what you are actually asking.

Comment: You need to make it clearer what you want. The only thing that is clear is that you want as output a PDF file using A4 pages. So: Combine all JPG on *one* PDF page? Or one/multiple JPG per PDF page? With or without a page margin? If you provide the specification of what you want, it would be easy to write a small script that does exactly what you want.